# Reduce cannot infer proper method version

Tags: java, java-stream, supplier

I would like to make my code more generic. And in order to achieve that, I proved as method parameters both a list and a supplier.

It turns out that `reduce()` cannot infer specific method in case where there are multiple to choose (see screenshot below).

How do I declare the method-version I would like to use?

```
public BigDecimal methodCalculate(List<MyObject> list, Supplier<? extends BigDecimal> getValue) {
    BigDecimal sum = list.stream()
            .filter(item -> item.getPremium())
            .map(item -> getValue)
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
    return sum;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are ***two issues*** I see in the code:

- `map` operation creates a stream of `Supplier`, **not** `BigDecimal`. Probably your intention was to use the supplier:

```
.map(item -> getValue.get())
```

- Your `Supplier` is of type `Supplier<? extends BigDecimal>` therefore with the fix above you would have a stream `Stream<? extends BigDecimal>`, **not** a stream `Stream<BigDecimal>`.

***Note:*** that there's no need to do anything special to make the compiler resolve the method reference `BigDecimal::add` because only one overloaded version of `add()` is applicable based on the number of arguments. This reference should be classified as a ***reference to an instance method of a particular object*** because it represents an implementation of `BinaryOperator<BigDecimal>`, which expects two arguments of type `BigDecimal`, i.e. the method would be invoked on the first parameter of the operator and the second would serve as an argument. And there's only one version of `add()` expecting a single argument, the flavor of `add()` that takes a `MathContext` as an additional parameter isn't applicable here (*for more information on method references, [see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)*).

But although method `add()` is accessible with the *hypothetical subtype* of `BigDecimal` and compiler is capable to resolve the required version of `add()` the code would not compile.

The flavor of reduce [`reduce(identity,accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) should have exactly the same return type (which is the same as the *identity* type) as the *type of elements* in the stream. But based on the provided *identity* return type of `reduce` would be `BigDecimal`, meanwhile in the stream we have `? extends BigDecimal`. That would cause a compilation error.

We can fix both bullet-points by changing the type of supplier to `Supplier<BigDecimal>`, since there are no subtypes of `BigDecimal` in JDK:

```
public BigDecimal methodCalculate(List<MyObject> list,
                                  Supplier<BigDecimal> getValue) {

    return list.stream()
        .filter(item -> item.getPremium())
        .map(item -> getValue.get())
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

If you can't change the type of the *supplier*, then you need another flavor of [`reduce(identity,accumulator,combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)), which is capable to have an *identity* (i.e. *return type* as well) that differs from the *type of elements* in the stream:

```
public BigDecimal methodCalculate(List<MyObject> list,
                                  Supplier<? extends BigDecimal> getValue) {
    
    return list.stream()
        .filter(item -> item.getPremium())
        .map(item -> getValue.get())
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add, BigDecimal::add);
}
```